# how to toggle an element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a navbar using HTML, CSS and JS. However, I am having a problem trying to toggle the hamburger so when you click the hamburger once the slide menu slide out and when you click the hamburger again it hides the slide menu.

To do this I created two functions and I call the `opennav` function inline.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik');
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif
}

.topnav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #122B3C;
  height: 65px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.home-hamburger {
  position: static;
}

.nav-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  /* halve the width of the image */
}

.doch {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 7px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #304C58;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #122B3C;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

3 @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#home"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <a href="#news">
    <div id="toggle" class="hamburger" onclick="openNav()">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Top Navigation with Centered and Right-Aligned Links</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">What we do</a>
  <a href="#">How we do it</a>
  <a href="#">Team</a>
  <a href="#">Work for us</a>
  <a href="#">Jobs</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

the Codeine to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/JadoyR

Comment: Please choose an answer if any has helped you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necesarily need jQuery for this. Your current plain JS logic can easily be amended to make this work as you require.

Firstly, do not use inline event handlers or CSS, both are bad practice. Instead, use unobtrusive event handlers. Then you can create a single event handler which opens and closes the menu by toggling a CSS class on the element which sets the desired `width` on the element. Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik');
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif
}

.topnav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #122B3C;
  height: 65px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.home-hamburger {
  position: static;
}

.nav-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  /* halve the width of the image */
}

.doch {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 7px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #304C58;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav.open {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #122B3C;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

3 @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#home"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <a href="#news">
    <div id="toggle" class="hamburger">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Top Navigation with Centered and Right-Aligned Links</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">What we do</a>
  <a href="#">How we do it</a>
  <a href="#">Team</a>
  <a href="#">Work for us</a>
  <a href="#">Jobs</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

If you do want to use jQuery then change the JS to:

```
$(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#mySidenav').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the javascript toggle method

https://codepen.io/gezzasa/pen/aaOaGN

Changed your `openNav()` to `toggleNav()`

Target the same element still

```
function toggleNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle("navWidth");
}
```

I also added the class for the width

```
.navWidth {width: 350px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

In css file

```
.toggleClsss{
  width:250px !important;
}
```

In Js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hamburger").click(function(){       
         $('#mySidenav').toggleClass('toggleClsss');
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to never use `!important`. Rather strengthen how you select the element. In future `!important` can cause you and anyone else working on your code a lot of issues.

Comment: Sure but some time we need to add important property to override old properly. and add new property.

Comment: Sometimes, sure, but it should always be a last resort. Improving selector precedence is by far the better method.,

Comment: @VishnuChauhan If your markup is good you'll never need to use it. You can change the way you select an element. Make it stronger.

Comment: @Gezzasa yes sure